# Stacked percentage barplot with error bars in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to create a stacked bar chart displaying percentages of values presented in two columns of a dataframe.

I have two problems with the stacked bar chart my code generates, that I think are linked.
[image]

1. `ggplot2` will not let me display %, but shows the input values as a share of 1.0. I cannot fix it with `scale_y_continuous(labels = percent_format())` which I found when looking around here at SO, so I am at loss on how to solve this?
2. My error bars are extremely long. Perhaps this is because the SEM is counted on percent but my graph is presenting share out of 1.0. So all values are 1/100 of what they are in my data frame?

My dataframe:

```
ID Group Labeled Unlabeled
A     0       2        98
B     0       2        98
C     0       4        96
D     0       4        96
E     0       4        96
A     1      50        50
B     1      40        60
C     1      50        50
D     1      40        60
E     1      30        70
A     2      30        70
B     2      30        70
C     2      20        80
D     2      20        80
E     2      20        80
A     3      10        90
B     3      10        90
C     3       5        95
D     3      10        90
E     3       5        95
A     4       2        98
B     4       2        98
C     4       1        99
D     4       1        99
E     4       0       100
```

My code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plyr)
library(reshape2)


#Calculate means for both groups
melted <- melt(data, id.vars=c("ID", "Group"))
means <- ddply(melted, c("variable", "Group"), summarise,
           mean=mean(value))

#Draw bar plot with ggplot2
plot <- ggplot(data=means, aes(x=Group, y=mean, fill=variable)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity",
       position="fill",
       width = 0.4) +                           
  xlab(" ") + ylab("Percentage (%)") + 
  theme_classic(base_size = 16, base_family = "Helvetica") + 
  theme(axis.text.y=element_text(size=16, face="bold")) + 
  theme(axis.title.y=element_text(size=16, face="bold", vjust=1)) + 
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=45,hjust=1,vjust=1, size=16, face="bold")) +
  theme(legend.position="right")

# Calc SEM  
means.sem <- ddply(melted, c("variable", "Group"), summarise,
               mean=mean(value), sem=sd(value)/sqrt(length(value)))
means.sem <- transform(means.sem, lower=mean-sem, upper=mean+sem)

# Add SEM & change appearance of barplot
plotSEM <- plot + geom_errorbar(data=means.sem, aes(ymax=upper,  ymin=lower), position="fill", width=0.15)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should also work (you just need to adjust the error-bars for the Labeled variable) and default position stack should work.

```
plot <- ggplot(data=means, aes(x=Group, y=mean, fill=variable)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity",
           width = 0.4) +                           
  xlab(" ") + ylab("Percentage (%)") + 
  theme_classic(base_size = 16, base_family = "Helvetica") + 
  theme(axis.text.y=element_text(size=16, face="bold")) + 
  theme(axis.title.y=element_text(size=16, face="bold", vjust=1)) + 
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=45,hjust=1,vjust=1, size=16, face="bold")) +
  theme(legend.position="right")

# Calc SEM  
means.sem <- ddply(melted, c("variable", "Group"), summarise,
                   mean=mean(value), sem=sd(value)/sqrt(length(value)))
means.sem <- transform(means.sem, lower=mean-sem, upper=mean+sem)
means.sem[means.sem$variable=='Labeled',5:6] <- means.sem[means.sem$variable=='Labeled',3] + means.sem[means.sem$variable=='Unlabeled',5:6]

# Add SEM & change appearance of barplot
plotSEM <- plot + geom_errorbar(data=means.sem, aes(ymax=upper,  ymin=lower), 
                                width=0.15)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Your answer is particularly helpful because of being close to what I wrote, so I can see where I erred more easily. When I run both your code and the code of the other reply, I generate a graph with the "Labeled" fraction down and the "Unlabeled" fraction up, but with the error bars in the same positions as in your reply (=inverted in relation to the graph). I actually want the "Labeled" fraction down, but I am failing to move the error bars to match them. I tried to play with the "position" variable, but without any success. Do you know where I am failing?

Comment: if that's the case, then you need to replace the line `means.sem[means.sem$variable=='Labeled',5:6] <- means.sem[means.sem$variable=='Labeled',3] + means.sem[means.sem$variable=='Unlabeled',5:6]` by `means.sem[means.sem$variable=='Unlabeled',5:6] <- means.sem[means.sem$variable=='Unlabeled',3] + means.sem[means.sem$variable=='Labeled',5:6]`

Answer (score 1):

1. You usually need the `scales` package for `format_percent()` to work, but we'll use a custom function for this
2. I tweaked you code a bit, but the main differences are:

   1. `position = 'stack'` on the bars instead of `fill`
   2. `position = 'identity'` and `stat = 'identity'` for the errorbars
   3. Display only one errorbars per group

#### Data:

```
df <- read.table(text = "ID Group Labeled Unlabeled
             A     0       2        98
             B     0       2        98
             C     0       4        96
             D     0       4        96
             E     0       4        96
             A     1      50        50
             B     1      40        60
             C     1      50        50
             D     1      40        60
             E     1      30        70
             A     2      30        70
             B     2      30        70
             C     2      20        80
             D     2      20        80
             E     2      20        80
             A     3      10        90
             B     3      10        90
             C     3       5        95
             D     3      10        90
             E     3       5        95
             A     4       2        98
             B     4       2        98
             C     4       1        99
             D     4       1        99
             E     4       0       100", header = T)
```

#### Code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(scales)

df %>% 
  gather('key','value',-ID, -Group) %>% 
  group_by(Group, key) %>% 
  summarise(mean = mean(value),
            sem = sd(value) / sqrt(n()),
            lower = (mean - sem),
            upper = (mean + sem))-> newdf

#Draw bar plot with ggplot2
plot <- ggplot(data=newdf, aes(x=Group, y=mean, fill=key)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity",
           position="stack",
           width = 0.4) +
  geom_errorbar(data = filter(newdf, key == 'Unlabeled'), aes(ymax=upper,  ymin=lower), stat = 'identity', position = 'identity', width=0.15) +
  xlab(" ") + 
  ylab("Percentage (%)") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = function(bs) {paste0(bs, '%')}) +
  theme_classic(base_size = 16, base_family = "Helvetica") + 
  theme(axis.text.y=element_text(size=16, face="bold"), 
        axis.title.y=element_text(size=16, face="bold"),
        axis.text.x=element_text(angle=45,hjust=1,vjust=1, size=16, face="bold"),
        legend.position="right")
```

#### Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that was a very helpful answer and I learned extra much because of the scales suggestion which I hadn't understood how to use exactly from looking at other users questions. When I run this code, for some reason, I generate a graph with the "Labeled" part down and the "Unlabeled" part up, but with the error bars in the same positions as in your reply. I actually want the "Labeled" part down, but I am having problems getting the error bars into the same position. I tried to play with the "position" variable, but the answer does not seem to be there?

Comment: This works with 2 categories but not with multiple categories. Error bars appear at wrong locations.